# SQL - count dates that are between same dates every year

Tags: sql, sql-server, between

I have a table with the following rows:

```
    date            
 2018-09-01           
 2018-10-01     
 2019-01-01
 2019-09-01
 2020-03-01
 2020-08-01
```

Let's say fiscal year starts in October of the previous year and ends in September of that year. So fiscal year 2020 would be from `2019-10-01` to `2020-09-30`. I am trying to count the dates that fall within each fiscal year so create the following table:

```
  date_count     fiscal_year    
      1              FY18
      3              FY19           
      2              FY20
```

I've tried the following to get a single year:

```
SELECT count(*) as date_count, 'FY18' as fiscal_year
FROM table_name
WHERE date between '2017-10-01' and '2018-09-30'
```

and I get

```
  date_count     fiscal_year    
      1              FY18
```

But I need to do this for every fiscal year. I've seen similar answers online but none that has the date counts. Would I need to use a recursive query?

Comment: A [calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) makes this a trivial task and has many, MANY uses and advantages. Are you aware that fiscal years can be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add 3 months and extract the year:

```
select t.*,
       year(dateadd(month, 3, date)) as fiscal_year
from t;
```